# can you put 2 tv antenna on the same mast for better reception?

Tags: signal, antenna

I live about 40 miles from Toledo and 60 miles from Ft Wayne. I have a directional antenna now that only pulls in either market.  I think I can get Toledo with an omni directional antenna but I need the directional antenna for Ft Wayne and I would like to have both available.  Can you put 2 tv antenna on the same mast for better reception? And does just being on the same mast combine the signals or do you have to wire the antenna together into the cable wire?

Comment: Consider a pre-amp, antenna booster to increase your received signal.

Comment: Why not install an antenna rotor to point the antenna at the various sources?  Adjusting the rotor was all part of changing the tv channel when I was a kid.

Answer (score 4):

You can't wire two antennas together because each antenna presents an impedance to the feed cable and TV that needs to be kept under control. Without controlled impedance matching you could end up with zero signal being received.

Therefore you can't just join up two antennas unless you really know what you are doing and of course there will be some losses that are inevitable. Those losses (even when you have done the best you can to match impedances and splice things together properly) might be enough to get really crappy reception from either antenna.

So it is best to use two antenna feed wires and have a selector box at the TV.

Regards having the two antennas close, this can cause other problems in that an antenna likes to have space around itself or the field patterns get disturbed. Again, a guy knowing what he is doing might be able to get the two antennas within a metre of each other but someone who doesn't know what they are doing is probably best to keep them as far apart as they can be and pointing in different directions.

Any radio antenna has a capture aperture (basically an area in square feet or sq metres) that is like the lens on a telescope - get in the way of that lens and you are reducing the signal. That aperture is usually a fair bit bigger than the mechanical dimensions of the physical antenna so this underpins what I said earlier - point them in different directions and keep them apart.

Comment: Thanx this doesn't make sense initially to the uninformed but now that I hear the science behind it I understand.

Comment: Ok, please consider formally accepting this answer or if there's something that I might still be able to help you with on this question, please ask.

Answer (score -1):

Put them at least one wavelength apart, at the lowest TV station frequency.

If you have vertical room.

Install the Yagi at the top, the Omni a meter or 2 lower down.

My rule of thumb for an OMNI is that it grabs the RF energy arriving in ONE SQUARE WAVELENGTH. If you have 10dB YAGI (10X the power), then it grabs the RF energy in 3 * 3 wavelength aperature.

Comment: Your last paragraph is poorly constructed. The effective aperture is a function of gain but there is no direct correlation of effective aperture to how large of an area of the plane wave from which the linear antenna gathers power. Also consider that an "omni" antenna can have gain as well.

Comment: And then the omni at the bottom with the mast next to it? Normally the omni is at the top.

Comment: Why not give preference to freedom from roof/wall interference to the Yagi?